# Format of phone number in imported contacts

Tags: contacts, import

I created a VCF file (VCARD version 2.1) of contacts and imported it into an Android 5 phone. A Motorola Moto G 2nd generation.

The VCF has phone numbers formatted correctly for the UK (e.g. "01234 567890")

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;John;Smith
FN:John Smith
TEL;HOME;VOICE:01234 567890
REV:20150824T162717Z
END:VCARD
```

but Android has altered them to a format that looks like a US format ("012-345-67890).

How can I stop this happening?